# Deep linking. Is it possible to create intent filter to detect urls without https or http scheme?

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking

I'm trying to get deep linking working in my app. I'd like to detect three url types: one with https (for example https://my-app.com), one with http (http://my-app.com) and one without any scheme (my-app.com). First two works just fine, but how to get third one working?

So far i get this code:

```
<intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="my-app.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="my-app.com"
                android:scheme="https" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I tried with `<data android:scheme="my-app.com" />`, but no luck.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: "and one without any scheme" -- I cannot think of any circumstance where `ACTION_VIEW` will be used with a `Uri` without a scheme.

Comment: So you're saying it's not possible to achive?

Comment: I am saying that it is unnecessary. It is also impossible to achieve, though. You cannot filter on `host` without filtering on `scheme`.

Comment: you can't skip scheme unfortunately

Comment: I was expecting that it won't be possible. Thank you.